# How to suppress/mute Maya script editor warning correctly with Python or Mel?

Tags: python, maya, mel

I need to open some large/messy Maya scenes from other artists. It always prompts out a lot of warnings and freezes Maya for a long time. I try to write a custom "open file" with python to suppress warning messages. But it seems not really "mute" script editor entirely. Let's say, when I open Hypershade window after open file, warnings prompt out again since I have lots of missing textures. The script I use now is:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel
filename = cmds.fileDialog2(fileMode=1)
reporter = mel.eval( 'string $tmp = $gCommandReporter;' )
cmds.scriptEditorInfo(reporter,suppressWarnings=True,suppressInfo=1,se=1,ch=1)
cmds.disableIncorrectNameWarning() 
cmds.file( filename[0], i=True );
```

Thank you

Comment: why not using a script to fix missing textures ? like deleting them or put placeholders ?

Comment: Hi, because it's not only missing texture but other stuff too. And this large file only acts as the reference so I don't really want to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

So basically this works:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.scriptEditorInfo(suppressWarnings=0,suppressInfo=0,se=0)
```

The reason I couldn't get it to work is that I use Charcoal Editor for Maya to write python. It somehow not suppress warnings. After I unload it everything is ok.